# Could I install jhipster with a firebird database?

Tags: java, jhipster, firebird

I have a database with firebird and I need to be able to integrate it with jhipster

I searched the Internet and could not find information

Comment: well, at first sight, I would say give it a try and come back with the issues if any

Comment: Probably not by default, but as JHipster is basically just Spring Boot + extras, you might be able to get it to work with manual changes.

Comment: like @MarkRotteveel said, Jhipster backend is a Spring Boot application, so you have to change datasource properties on aplication-{profile}.yml, url jdbc driver, etc... then test if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a small experiment and although adding Jaybird (Firebird JDBC driver) and switching to a Firebird JDBC URL for an existing database and using the Firebird Hibernate dialect allows JHipster to connect, you then need to correct the generated database model to get it to actually work. Liquibase doesn't support a number of Liquibase features with Firebird and doesn't automatically quote keywords, the Hibernate dialect tries to use a sequence table instead of the created sequence, and probably other things I haven't yet run into.

Long story short, it might work, but definitely not out of the box.

I specifically did the following:

- Added Jaybird dependency. With gradle add `implementation "org.firebirdsql.jdbc:jaybird-jdk18"` to the `dependencies` section of `build.gradle`
- Modified `application-dev.yml` to use Firebird (leaving out unchanged properties):

  ```
  spring:
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/jhipsterexperiment?charSet=utf-8
      username: jhipsterexperiment
      password: jhipsterexperiment
    jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect
      database: DEFAULT
  ```
- I then ran the application and fixed Liquibase errors

  - Removed the `startValue` and `incrementBy` properties from a `createSequence` element
  - Commented out (removed) `addNotNullConstraint` elements
  - Explicitly quoted a column name `value` from `<column name="value" type="varchar(255)"/>` to `<column name="&quot;VALUE&quot;" type="varchar(255)"/>`

Afterwards, my jhipster application started up, but attempts to log in fail because Hibernate tries to use a table called `SEQUENCE_GENERATOR` instead of a sequence with that name. At that point I stopped investigating further.